# Python list index out of range in for loop

Tags: python, api, for-loop, request

With the aviationstack API, I try to get info about every flight departing from Marseille (France) airport.

I use the first steps to determine how many pages I have to iterate, as the API returns the total number of results and documentation says the default response has a limit of 100 results, then I build URL's according to the latter result.

Though the code below could be simplified, it gives promising results, however at the last step, I need to provide `counts` at the line `flight_data = response.get("data")` in order to get every item of each offset.

But it returns `IndexError: list index out of range`. I guess because the last offset contains less than 100 items.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

from pprint import pprint

airport = 'LFML' # ICAO code for Marseille Provence airport, France
KEY = XXX

urllst = []
responselist = []
countlst = []
data = []

# determine how many results we get
urlroot = f'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key={KEY}&dep_icao={airport}'
r = requests.get(urlroot)
resp = r.json()
total_results = resp.get("pagination").get("total")
pprint(f'there are {total_results} results in total')

# the total number of results gives us the offset number
offsetnumber = round(total_results, -2)
pprint(f'offset number for {airport} is then {offsetnumber}')

# build URL's according to the offset numbers we obtained
for i in range(0, offsetnumber + 100, 100):
  urls = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key='+KEY+'&limit=100&offset='+str(i)+'&dep_icao='+airport
  urllst.append(urls)

# call the API and store the responses in a list
for url in urllst:
  req = requests.get(url)
  responses = req.json()
  responselist.append(responses)

# get the count of results by offset
for response in responselist:
  counts = response.get("pagination").get("count")
  offset = response.get("pagination").get("offset")
  pprint(f'there are {counts} results in offset {offset}')
  countlst.append(counts)
  
  flight_data = response.get("data")[counts`]
  flight = flight_data.get('flight').get('icao')
  #print(f"{flight}")
  #print(flight)
  data.append((flight))
  cols=['flights']

result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
result
```

Comment: `response.get("data")` returned an empty sequence, so item `[0]` is out of range.

Comment: To check the length of a list there is "len". If the list contains at least one item, index -1 addresses the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
    flight_data = response.get("data")[0]
    flight = flight_data.get('flight').get('icao')
    data.append((flight))
```

with this:

```
    data.extend(
        flight_data.get('flight').get('icao')
        for flight_data in response.get('data')
    )
```

to append each `flight` element to `data` instead of just the first one.  If `response.get('data')` is empty, this will be an empty sequence so nothing will get appended (instead of raising an error).